# Spring Boot Actuator Custom RestControllerEndpoint with RequestMapping Annotation on class level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have some custom actuator endpoints which should have the same parameters after the endpoint id. Therefore I use the `@RestEndpointController` annotation to get "full" control over the endpoints via MVC annotations. But I recognized a problem when I use the `@RequestMapping` annotation on class level on my RestEndpointController class.

My sample implementation:

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "tenant")
@RequestMapping("customer/{id}")
public class TenantEndpoint {

    @GetMapping
    public String getTenantById(@PathVariable("id") String customerId) {
        return "Tenant_" + customerId;
    }
}
```

with the following application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, tenant
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when running this app, there are two endpoints registered in Spring Boot

- /actuator/tenant/customer/{id}
- /customer/{id}

How can I avoid the second (non actuator) endpoint to be registered?
Or is it a bug of Actuator / Spring-Boot?

Comment: Remove `@Component` that isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `@RequestMapping` on class level. You can mention the subsequent path as part of `@GetMapping`. Below code will register only a single endpoint viz. `/actuator/tenant/customer/{id}`

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "tenant")
public class TenantEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
    public String getTenantById(@PathVariable("id") String customerId) {
        return "Tenant_" + customerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59632803/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

you should try, I didn't check it, bring some feedback in case you test it please.

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "tenant")
@RequestMapping("customer")
public class TenantEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getTenantById(@PathVariable("id") String customerId) {
        return "Tenant_" + customerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested it, its the same result